# Error with configured on your API key

Tags: wordpress, api, youtube

Error type: "Forbidden". Error message: "The referrer null does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions." Domain: "usageLimits". Reason: "ipRefererBlocked".

I'm getting this error trying to use Youtube api with browser key.
On my wordpress site i'm already using maps api, which works fine with that same browser key.

What is going wrong?

Comment: I'd say that the key word in that sentence is: `null`. The host is not actually getting what you think he should be getting, namely, the "referrer" value probably ought not be null.  Look for a bug in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Google Dev Console: https://console.developers.google.com , then go to Credentials, then click on the neame of the API keys you are useing in your site, then add you domain name in the "Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites) (Optional)",

example:

```
*.yourdomain.com/*
```

note: you need go to domain verification area and verify that you own the domain, also make sure to enable "YouTube Data API" under "YouTube APIs"

Comment: I did already do all the steps you mentioned. When i try to use a playlist al works well. Only when i want to use a channel i get the error